# Wait for element without using promises (ES5)

Tags: javascript, dom, callback, settimeout

What is the best way to:

- wait for a DOM element to exist
- And then return true if it does?

I must use ES5, which rules out promises and async.

Here's an example I'm trying to work on below, which consoles.log `true` in `valueCallBack`, but doesn't return `true` (found variable).

```
function waitForElement(elementId, callBack){
    var found;
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var element = document.querySelector(elementId);

        found = true;
        valueCallBack(found)

        if(element) {
            callBack(elementId);
        } else {
            waitForElement(elementId, callBack);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function valueCallBack(found){
    // console.log("this console logs true", found);
    return found;
};


waitForElement('.select-fare-type-modal:not(.ng-hide)',function(){
    // ELEMENT FOUND AND DO SOMETHING
})
```

Comment: Yes good point, I've updated the question, to find out the best way to return true, if it does exist

Comment: *"And then return true"*: returning is something that happens synchronously. In a well designed asynchronous pattern, you would never attempt to return a future result now.

Comment: `found = true;
        valueCallBack(found)` make no sense, why is it set to true? You never verified if it was found....

Comment: "Needs to return true" So return true instead of returning the id..... `callBack(true);` Code should be as simple as `function waitForElement(elementId, callBack){
  function check() {
    if (document.getElementById(elementId)) callBack(true);
    else window.setTimeout(check, 1);
  }
  check();
}`

Comment: Why is there `valueCallBack` at all?

Comment: When you say ES5 what *exactly* are you targetting? [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the correct way to get notifications for added elements. It's available in ES5, since it's not actually an ES spec but DOM spec thing. Which browsers are you targetting, however?

Comment: Hi @VLAZ. - I've tried mutationObserver, but as it's async I have struggled specifcally `return true`. Not console.log etc, I haven't been able to `return true` using mutationObserver.

Comment: It is not possibly to do what you want synchronously. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is setting multiple timers. If you want your function to run after certain intervals, you can try with a simple `setInterval`.
Once your element is found (exists), you can clear the same interval using its ID.

```
let clearId = null;
function waitForElement(elementId, callBack){
    var found = false;
    clearId  = window.setInterval(function(){
        var element = document.querySelector(elementId);
  if(element){
   callBack();
}
    }, 1000);
}

let alertTrue = () => {
alert(true);
clearInterval(clearId);
}

waitForElement('#yourElementId',alertTrue );
```

Comment: Hey @tushar this is really helpful thank you!  I wondered though, if I replace `alert(true)`, with `return true`, why it doesn't return true? Thank you.

Comment: @ReenaVerma returning from a callback doesn't do much. This code is still asynchronous in nature, as it finishes *later*.